# can Javascript work without html?

Tags: javascript

I have made this Count Down  Timer in Java script.

Before this I thought JavaScript cannot make applications without html except when making alerts etc. So why isn't JavaScript used alone to build applications?

```
 <span id="countdown" class="timer"></span>
<script>
var seconds = 60;
function secondPassed() {
    var minutes = Math.round((seconds - 30)/60);
    var remainingSeconds = seconds % 60;
    if (remainingSeconds < 10) {
        remainingSeconds = "0" + remainingSeconds;  
    }
    document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = minutes + ":" + remainingSeconds;
    if (seconds == 0) {
        clearInterval(countdownTimer);
        document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = "Buzz Buzz";
    } else {
        seconds--;
    }
}

var countdownTimer = setInterval('secondPassed()', 1000);
</script>
```

[image]

Comment: You need some medium to show the result to end user. HTML provide you that.

Comment: JavaScript **is** use alone without HTML to make applications. Never heard of `Node JS` or `Windows Scripting Host`?

Comment: Answer is Yes. Look into `Node JS`. Also primary function of vanilla JS was to manipulate DOM elements, so you would need HTML.

Comment: You assign to `document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML`, which are HTML DOM functions. The browser simply creates some HTML document for you if you don't.

Comment: No, what JavaScript needs is the DOM, not HTML; you can make JavaScript write to XML or XHTML instead, for example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Javascript is used "alone" to make applications. But it needs an option to show the results.

This can be the command line (NodeJS, browser console), a network response (NodeJS), or a graphical interface (browser with either HTML, SVG, Canvas or WebGL).

In your case, you don't create a proper web page, so the browser interprets your output as a kind of "default html", which it shows to you unstyled. If you inspect that countdown in your developer tools, you will be able to look at the HTML that was generated for you.